# i can't properly understand how recursive functions work

Tags: javascript

So I debugged this function using the browser debugger to see how it works:

```js
function rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum) {
  console.log(`called with start: ${startNum} end: ${endNum}`)
  if (startNum === endNum) return [startNum];
  else if (startNum > endNum) return;
  else {
    let arr = rangeOfNumbers(startNum + 1, endNum);
    arr.unshift(startNum);
    return arr;
  }
};

console.log(rangeOfNumbers(0, 4))
```

So after the (let arr) part returns an array with [startNum], (startNum) is equal to 4 which is (endNum) (from the condition I set at first), from there (startNum) starts reducing by one and going from 3 till the (startNum) I set as an argument (0). How does this happen exactly? What makes it reduce every time?

Comment: Step through the code using a debugger. Almost all browsers have a built in one or you can attach an IDE. Inspect the values of the variables and use stepping (into/out of) to better understand what is happening.

Comment: add some `console.log('startNum', startNum)` to the snippet I just added to your code and see how the variable changes value.

Comment: Run it now, see if the logs help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've added some logs of what's happening in main branch of code. As you can see, while the code is called sequentially, incrementing `startNum` by one each time, the *result* of each call is handled in reverse:

1. The call to `rangeOfNumbers(4, 4)` returns `[4]`
2. The call to `rangeOfNumbers(3, 4)` receives the `[4]` from step 1 and adds `3` to the beginning of the array ([`unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift)).
3. The call to `rangeOfNumbers(2, 4)` receives the `[3,4]` from step 2 and adds `2` to the beginning of the array
4. The call to `rangeOfNumbers(1, 4)` receives the `[2,3,4]` from step 3 and adds `1` to the beginning of the array
5. The call to `rangeOfNumbers(0, 4)` receives the `[1,2,3,4]` from step 4 and adds `0` to the beginning of the array
6. And that's it...

```js
function rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum) {
  if (startNum === endNum) {
    let arr = [startNum];
    console.log('result of call with startNum:', startNum, ', endNum:', endNum, arr);
    return arr;
  } else if (startNum > endNum) { 
    return; 
  } else {
    let arr = rangeOfNumbers(startNum + 1, endNum);
    console.log('result of recursive call with startNum + 1:', startNum + 1, ', endNum:', endNum, arr);
    arr.unshift(startNum);
    console.log('after adding startNum to beginning of array:', startNum, arr);
    console.log('result of call with startNum:', startNum, ', endNum:', endNum, arr);
    return arr;
  }
};

console.log('final result', rangeOfNumbers(0, 4));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

lets call the rangeOfNumbers() function ron().  Your code executes as follows:

```
ron(0,4)
   ron(1,4)
      ron(2,4)
        ron(3,4)
           ron(4,4)
```

at:

```
ron(4,4) it returns 4
```

now we just work backwards and build arr up one element at a time. Also you don't need the else if in your code.